# Is square root of n closer to O(log n) or O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have two algorithms A and B.

Time complexity of algorithm A is *O*(log *n)* and that of B is *O*(*n*).

Now I have a new algorithm C that has time complexity of *O*(√*n*) I need to prove (mathematically) whether algorithm A or algorithm B is asymptotically closer to algorithm C.

Any help on this is well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10611663/1162233

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule - this way it is easy to show that logn goes slower towards infinity than sqrt(n).

Answer (score 4):

> Is square root of n closer to O(logn) or O(n)?

(I'm assuming in the following that you actually mean *Θ*, not *O* (thanks to WhatsUp for pointing that out). Otherwise, these are just upper bounds, and you can't say anything about the differences of functions bounded by upper bounds.)

Let's first start with the specific functions *log(n)*, *√n*, and *n*. Obviously, *log(n) ≤ √n ≤ n* (you can use L'Hospital's rule to see this). So the question is if *n - √n* is greater or less than *√n - log(n)*.

Applying L'Hospital's rule to

*lim<sub>n→∞</sub>(n - √n) / (√n - log(n))*,

you can see that this is

*lim<sub>n→∞</sub>(1 - 0.5 / √n) / (0.5 / √n - 1 / n) = lim<sub>n→∞</sub>(n - 0.5  √n) / (0.5  √n - 1) = lim<sub>n→∞</sub>(n - 0.5  √n) / (0.5  √n) = ∞*.

So *√n* is closer to *log(n)* than to *n*.

---

With *Θ* the calculations are essentially the same, but more tedious. You need to argue that every function is bounded between two constants, and use the upper and lower ones accordingly. Notwithstanding, categorically, if *f*, *g*, and *h* are *Θ(log(n))*, *Θ(√n)*, and *Θ(n)*, then for large enough *n*, *g(n) - f(n) << h(n) - g(n)*.

Comment: @WhatsUp I don't think it's a nonsense question.

Comment: Let's say the input is measured in `log(n)` bits. Then an `O(log n)` algorithm is polynomial, while both `O(sqrt(n))` and `O(n)` are exponential.

Comment: @WhatsUp to different exponents.

Comment: To say in another way: suppose you are in a programming test. An `O(log n)` solution gets 10 points, an `O(sqrt(n))` solution 2 points, an `O(n)` solution 1 point. Which are closer?

Comment: That's basically what Maroun Maroun was saying in the first comment to this question...

Comment: @WhatsUp If you have 3 numbers *a < b < c*, and the question is whether *b* is closer to *a* or *c*, then the interpretation is whether *b - a* is smaller or larger than *c - b*. Here, for each value of *n*, these are just 3 numbers. I really don't see any ambiguity about it.

Comment: The problem is that we are talking about **algorithms**... so that it's nonsense to measure the absolute difference (also note that there is the big `O`, so they are not numbers). The word "closer" really needs to be defined here... And personally I really think an `O(sqrt(n))` algorithm is closer to an `O(n)` one than to an `O(log(n))` one.

Comment: @WhatsUp You do have a point about the O (thanks!), but, this being SO, it's very often used in the meaning of Theta (which is how I interpret the question). Theta, of course, would not change anything in the above. Other than that, I really don't see your point. Algorithms have running times that are just numbers. If you consider inputs, the running times are functions that output numbers. You can then group these functions according to complexity families. Basically, the question is whether any members of these complexity families, for any *n*, would have 3 numbers with some property - yes.

Comment: So according to your logic, a `Theta(n/2)` algorithm will be closer to a `Theta(log(n))` one than to a `Theta(n)` one, because `n - n/2 > n/2 - log(n)`?

Comment: @WhatsUp No, because for your example, the use of L'hospital would be completely wrong. That is absolutely not the case here.  You do not know that the difference between Theta(n) and Theta(n / 2) tends to infinity. In fact, you don't know it's even positive.

Comment: Well, I just changed `sqrt(n)` to `n/2` ... your calculations still work, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126240/discussion-between-ami-tavory-and-whatsup).

Comment: Big thanks @AmiTavory for your answer! I think you're right. The issue in comparing these time complexities came from analyzing a compromise data structure with a search of 'code'O(sqrt(n))'code', compared to sorted array (efficient search 'code'O(log(n))'code', inefficient insert/delete 'code'O(n)'code') and dynamically linked list (inefficient search 'code'O(n)'code', efficient insert/delete 'code'O(1)'code').

Comment: @AkuSilvenius Since you seem relatively new to the site, note that you can upvote and/or accept answers that addressed your question.